# PHP mailing function

Tags: php, phpmailer

In below code I am trying to use **PHP mail function**, where an agent after registering in my site will get a mail in his/her account. But the code for mailing function I used doesn't work. My website is live and I am testing in live server. Can anyone just have look and guide me where I am wrong.

After filling all the details when I click on register Buttons ,it always execute the else part

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['reg_agent']))
{
$agent_name = $_POST['agent_name'];
$agent_name = mysql_real_escape_string($agent_name);
$agent_email = $_POST['agent_email'];
$agent_email = mysql_real_escape_string($agent_email);
$agent_password = $_POST['agent_password'];
$agent_password = mysql_real_escape_string($agent_password);

$subject = "Activate Your Account";
$message = "Dear ".$agent_name.", \n
Thank you for registering at our website, http://www.*****.com!

You are two steps away from logging in and interacting with our site.

To activate your membership, please click here: http://www.*****.com/agent.php?agent_email=$agent_email

Once you activate your membership, you will be able to login with the following information:
Email-Id: ".$agent_email."
Password: ".$agent_password."

Thanks!
******

This is an automated response, please do not reply!";
$header = "vikrampatnaik.dev@gmail.com";
$retval = mail ($agent_email,$subject,$message,$header);

if($retval == true)
{
 mkdir("agents/".$agent_name);
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `agent_job_status`(agent_name, agent_email, agent_mobile, agent_password, agent_city, agent_location)
                    VALUES ('$agent_name', '$agent_email', '$agent_mobile', '$agent_password', '$agent_state3', '$agent_location')");

    echo '<div class="alert alert-success signin"  style="text-align: center;"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>';
    echo 'Congrats! <strong>"'.$agent_name. '"</strong> you have successfully created your account &nbsp;&nbsp; 
    Your membership information has been mailed to your email address! Please check your email and follow the instructions!' ;
    echo '</div>';

}
else{
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button> ';
    echo mysql_error() ;

    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success signin" style="text-align: center;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>';
    echo "Message could not be sent...";
    echo "</div>";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this a textbook example of how not to send email from PHP. I'd suggest you scrap it and start again. Don't use `mysql_*` functions. And PHP 4.1.8?? That's *13 years* out of date!

Comment: Its PHP version 5.4.33

Comment: While running those code in localhost it executing the `If statement` but while running those code in live server it executing the `else statement`... No error on any `mysql functions` , just the `mail function` is not working in live server  .

Comment: In order for `mail()` to work you have to give it a valid, correctly-encoded RFC822 message, complete with headers. You can't just throw some text at it and hope it works. I suggest you use a mail library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to do all this for you - it's much better than just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1) The additional header you're sending in `$header` isn't valid.  Assuming you meant vikrampatnaik.dev@gmail.com as the "From" address, your header variable should be:

```
$header = 'From: vikrampatnaik.dev@gmail.com';
```

2) Unless, in this case, you are using gmail's SMTP, your message has a high probability of being blocked as spam.  That's because your "From" address won't match the server that's really sending the message.  To improve the chance of your message to actually be delivered, you should have a From address that matches your domain and put your gmail address as a Reply-to, like this:

```
$header = 'From: no-reply@***yourdomain***.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: vikrampatnaik.dev@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: do i have to add MIME-Version and Content-Type

Comment: If you want to send HTML email, yes.  Otherwise, no.

Comment: sorry to bother you david, but i tried using both, it is executing the else part every time.

Do I have to change any setting in my cpanel Email Authentication

Comment: Have you tried using `error_get_last()` to see what the error is?  Try adding `print_r(error_get_last());` in your else section and see what it says...

Comment: Just `1` and nothing else?  There should be more of an error message than that, something like `[type] => 2 [message] => mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "x.x.x.x" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() [file] => C:\www\X\X.php [line] => 2` (or whatever the error is)

Comment: no nothing like that david. And now it doesn't show that 1 also.output is blank now.

Comment: `$subject = "Activate Your Account In www.*****.com";
    $message = "Dear ".$agent_name.", ; 
    $headers = 'From: mypropertydoor.com <vikrampatnaik.dev@gmail.com>' ;  
    $retval = mail($agent_email,$subject,$message, $headers); 

    if($retval == true)
    {
     
        echo "Message sent successfully...";
        
    }
    else{        
        print_r(error_get_last());        
    }`

Comment: Looks like a missing quote -- $message = "Dear ".$agent_name.", `"`; -- that could be causing the blank output

Comment: Also which php version are you using?

Comment: php version  4.1.8.

....I tried after removing that quote nothing happened  output is blank...

Comment: Oh, that's pretty old.  error_get_last only works with PHP >= 5.2.  The [php manual page about error_get_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) has a user contributed note from "php at joert dot net" which may help in your case to see what the error is.

Comment: oh sorry its  PHP version 5.4.33  @David R.... Well while running the code in localhost its executing the `If Statement`  but executing the `else` in live server.

Comment: Interesting.  There's got to be some way to find out what the error is.  Is there an `error_log`?  Or have you tried `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your code?

Comment: yeah there is an error_log file in root folder... yeah I tried using `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` nothing happened . Output is still blank

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I had to install "sendmail" to solve it.
On linux its installed this way:

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Comment: what about windows...Any idea on that.

Comment: you will find its version to install on windows.